recording logger result to a cell [solved]
I have a script that creates a new folder ID and displays the ID in the Execution log.
I want to record that folder ID to cell A1.
I thought it would be as simple as
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().sourceSheet.getRange("A1").setValues(newFolderID);

where newFolderID = parentFolder.createFolder(newFoldername).getId();
What am I doing wrong?
The script to create the folder works fine, it's just recording the FolderID into a cell.
Updated
Solution used as per @PatrickdC's suggestion.
I changed my initial attempt:
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().sourceSheet.getRange("A1").setValues(newFolderID);

to:
sourceSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(newFolderID);

This is the solution that worked for me.
Many thanks

Only use 'setValue' (without an s) because you are only writing 1 value to 1 cell.

Thanks @PatrickdC. I'm getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRange')". What am I not defining?

What is sourceSheet? You can't make up methods as your wish... Search the documentation of class Spreadsheet for the list of available methods.

sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");

I have sorted it.

If sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN"); then you should delete SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(). and only use sourceSheet.getRange("A1").setValues(newFolderID);

That is of course assuming that ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

If you have solved the problem, you might answer the question to share how you solved it; if there isn't an answer, you might delete it.

If you still having the issue I advise you to post  a minimal reproducible example.
or if you managed to solve the issue, consider posting it as an answer.
